# Generate a HTML table report using AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I have my server logs, in the following format, is it possible to convert this in a tabular format ?

**Server Log:-**

```
####&lt;Jun 1, 2014 9:28:49 AM EDT&gt; &lt;Error&gt; &lt;JMX&gt; &lt;Host1&gt; &lt;pnbprod01&gt; &lt;[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: &#39;21&#39; for queue: &#39;weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)&#39;&gt; &lt;&lt;anonymous&gt;&gt; &lt;&gt; &lt;&gt; &lt;1401629329071&gt; &lt;BEA-149500&gt; &lt;An exception occurred while registering the MBean null.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registered more than one instance with the same objectName : com.bea:ServerRuntime=server01,Name=&quot;http://server.com/:QueryInterfaceServicePort:http://192.168.56.1/epics/services/queryInterface:&quot;,ApplicationRuntime=PNB,Type=WseeClientRuntime,EJBComponentRuntime=lib/CodingServicesEJB.jar new:weblogic.wsee.monitoring.WseeClientRuntimeMBeanImpl@4b7fbc82 - /pnbprod01[ServerRuntime]/PNB[J2EEApplicationRuntimeMBeanImpl]/lib/CodingServicesEJB.jar[EJBComponentRuntimeMBeanImpl]/
```

Something like this ?

**Tabular form:-**

```
Column1                         Column2   Column3 Column4 
Jun 1, 2014 9:28:49 AM EDT      Error      JMX    An exception occurred while registering
```

Comment: Where does `JMX` come from in your log? Where does the text `An exception occurred...` come from?

Comment: Show us your attempts

Comment: which type Table you what? Have you think how can you arrange above log in Tabular from? what is in `Column1                         Column2   Column3 Column4` ?First you arrange above log in Table form roughly.

Comment: All of the items in your table do not appear in the log example you provided ?

Comment: Sorry Mark this due to html encoding issue, the gt(>) and lt(<) then symbol probably! Fixed it now !

Comment: @ThiruArasu the text `JMX` being present in your output but not in your input is not an HTML encoding issue. Also, we need to see more than the treatment of what appears to be 1 2-line input record to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

Set field separator to <
Write out titles

check for timestamp on line

Parse the right pieces of info you want based on position and field separator

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="<"; print "\nColumn 1\t\t\tColumn 2\tColumn 3\tColumn 4" } /[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ { gsub(">", ""); print $2"\t"$3"\t\t"$4"\t\t"$14 }'
```